# rbenv install 2.6.3 BUILD FAILED

Tags: rbenv

I want to use rbenv for first time, install it and initialize it, after using rbenv install 2.6.3 (this version is in my list. rbenv install --list) I have BUILD FAILED (error about clang3.0 and gcc-4.0) how can I fix it? thank you.

I tried brew update and upgrade and git clone on my rbenv list for 2.6.3 and it is ok, and with gcc --version I get:
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4)

rbenv install 2.6.3

ruby-build: using openssl from homebrew
Downloading ruby-2.6.3.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.6/ruby-2.6.3.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.6.3...
ruby-build: using readline from homebrew

BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.13.2 using ruby-build 20190615-7-g0e9094b)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/r2/1kkj8jmd5cz_hcl22vs96pzm0000gn/T/ruby-build.20190720165009.5566
Results logged to /var/folders/r2/1kkj8jmd5cz_hcl22vs96pzm0000gn/T/ruby-build.20190720165009.5566.log

Last 10 log lines:
/var/folders/r2/1kkj8jmd5cz_hcl22vs96pzm0000gn/T/ruby-build.20190720165009.5566/ruby-2.6.3 /var/folders/r2/1kkj8jmd5cz_hcl22vs96pzm0000gn/T/ruby-build.20190720165009.5566 ~
checking for ruby... /usr/local/bin/ruby
tool/config.guess already exists
tool/config.sub already exists
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin17.3.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin17.3.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin17.3.0
./configure: line 3491: /usr/bin/gcc-4.0: No such file or directory
configure: error: clang version 3.0 or later is required
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

Answer (score 1):

Fix: `RUBY_CFLAGS="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration" rbenv install 2.6.3`